# Unexpected keyword 'this' in React class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am getting an error Unexpected keyword 'this' while trying to update react state using Redux saga. Can someone explain to me what is the issue with the below code and how to rectify it?

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
 
   removeCartItems = (cartItems) => {
        cartItems.map((product, index) => ({
            this.props.dispatch(removeItem(product)) // Getting error Unexpected keyword 'this'
        }));
    };

  render() {
    this.removeCartItems(cartItems)
    return (<h1>Remove product from cart</h1>);
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `()` around the `{}`…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove parentheses otherwise JS will interpret this as though you are trying to return the object from an arrow function.

```
() => { this. ... }
```

Not

```
() => ({})
```

In your case, it will look in the following way.

```
    cartItems.map((product, index) => {
        this.props.dispatch(removeItem(product));
    });
```